# Rasterio showing single band images wrong

Tags: python, sentinel-2, rasterio, sentinel-1

I'm using rasterio in Python at the moment, and I have no problem when I'm dealing with RGB satellite images. However, if I try using singleband Sentinel 2 images, or a singleband Sentinel 1 image, something happens. As this figure here shows, you can see that the image on the left, is suddenly green. Whilst the exact same image on the right in QGIS, looks at it should. Any suggestions?

[image]

I use the following code:

```
dataset = rasterio.open(project_dir + '/data/satellite_data/S1/merged/S1HH.tiff')
img=dataset.read()
fig=show(img)
```

Comment: I found out that if I import it to QGIS first, then saves the layer as a geotiff. It gets saved as an RGBA file (4 channels), which then shows up correctly and I essentially got what I wanted. Then in python I just flatten the image.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the `import` statements so we can see what libraries you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't rasterio reading the raster incorrectly. It's whatever you are using to display the data (matplotlib?) applying a default colour ramp. By saving as an RGBA in QGIS you are changing (and destroying) the data.

Instead, assuming you're using `matplotlib`, use the `cmap` argument in [`pyplot.imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) to specify a grayscale colourmap, something like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import rasterio

dataset = rasterio.open(project_dir + '/data/satellite_data/S1/merged/S1HH.tiff')
img=dataset.read()
img_plt = pyplot.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
pyplot.show()
```

For a (very) basic contrast stretch:

```
import numpy as np

img[img == dataset.nodata] = np.nan  # Convert NoData to NaN
vmin, vmax = np.nanpercentile(img, (5,95))  # 5-95% stretch
img_plt = pyplot.imshow(img, cmap='gray', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Thank you Luke. Sounds plausible! (And important detail there!) I'll check it out tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: I couldn't wait, so snuck out of bed to check it out ;) That did the trick!  Thank you @Luke. Do you per chance know of any way to brighten the picture up a bit. It looks extremely dark compared to the QGIS viewer.

Comment: @Kongie.  look up contrast stretching. This is what QGIS does.  See edit.

Comment: perfect, think I found what I am looking for. Thank you =)